# "maze to end all mazes" meaning

Tags: expressions

I have come across this expression in a youtube video but couldn't figure out what it means: "maze to end all mazes". Could you please tell me what it means?

Answer (score 1):

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/the-to-end-all):

> **the...to end all...**
>
> the biggest, best, worst, etc. person or thing of their kind that there has ever been
>
> It was the party to end all parties.